# How to set TimeZone on MS Outlook app url invocation in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, outlook, timezone

You can open outlook and store an event using the following url in an iOS App:

```
"ms-outlook://events/new?title=%@&description=@%&start=@&end=%@&location=%@"
```

But how to set the time zone? It seems that the dates have to be always in the format of `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`.

Has someone got this working?

Comment: It looks like it's using RFC3339 formatting. https://medium.com/easyread/understanding-about-rfc-3339-for-datetime-formatting-in-software-engineering-940aa5d5f68a explains this and how to add a timezone offset at the end.  However, there's no guarantee outlook was coded to honor RFC3339 so... if you try it and it doesn't work, you may have to offset the timezone manually before passing the datetime in.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasRees! The article helped me a lot!